# Windows service going Idle

Tags: c#, .net, timer, windows-services

I developed windows service in .net. Its need to run for every 5 seconds. When I install and start my service it run Good. But after some time (1 or 2 days) it takes too much of time or even goes idle . Here my Start up code:

```
    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            processThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(this.InitTimer));
            processThread.Start();
        }
        catch (Exception failedtoStart)
        {
            DebugLog.LogAlert(failedtoStart.ToString(), 2);
        }
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        timer.Enabled = false;
    }

    private void Timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (isStarted)
            {
                isStarted = false;
                [Some function]
                isStarted = true;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            DebugLog.LogAlert("Error: " + ex, 1);
        }
    }

    private void InitTimer()
    {
        try
        {
            timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
            timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(Timer_Elapsed);
            timer.Interval = 5000;
            timer.Enabled = true;
            timer.Start();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            DebugLog.LogAlert("Error: " + ex, 1);
        }
    }
```

If i did anything wrong please correct me.

Comment: Are there any event logs on the server at the time of the service trying to restart to indicate what the load on the server is like at that point?  Code looks good as far as i can see.

Comment: @MaksimSimkin that's about a web server. Not for a windows service

Comment: The key might be the code in [Some function]. What does it do?

Comment: Why do you need it to be in a thread like that?

Comment: You timer is doing some work based on the isEnabled value. And you set it to false before you do some function, but if any exception happened in that function then the isEnabled is never set to true again. And your service will be idle, because the if statement is always false.

Comment: isEnabled is used to avoid the additional threds.

Comment: [Some Function] performs SQL operations. It need to read the datas from table at every 5 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

*I cannot comment yet.*
Looking at your code, you want to run the somefunction every 5 seconds but not at the same time.
Instead of maintaing a boolean to verify the method is currently running, you could disable the timer before running the function and enable after that.

```
try
  {
        timer.Enabled = false;
        [Some function]
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        DebugLog.LogAlert("Error: " + ex, 1);
    }
    Finally{
        timer.Enabled = true;
    }
```

As @Nawed Nabi Zada pointed out, you should reset the flag event incase of exception occured. your code is missing that.